# FolderDialog Box Crashing Only in Debug Mode VSD2008

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have a folderBrowseDialog box in an application.  It has been working for a month.  Lately when I run the project from VS 2008 and I click on a button that opens the box the command ShowDialog() runs.  The browser box shows up for a second and then I get "Windows encountered a problem box".

Now here is the interest thing, if I compile the project, whether it be in the Debug or Release profile, and navigate to the exe, everything runs fine.

Has anyone have this issue before?

I can post the details of the error report if it helps.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a shell dialog, you'll get the shell extensions injected into your process.  You probably got a lousy one that is causing the crash.  You can see them getting loaded with Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick Enabled unmanaged code debugging.  Pay attention to the Output window when you open the dialog, you'll see a line for each DLL getting loaded.

Short from uninstalling the trouble-maker, SysInterals' AutoRuns utility is a good way to disable shell extensions.

Comment: Interestingly enough just by enabling the unamaged code debugging stop the issue from occuring.  The dll loaded the first time are 

Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shfolder.dll'
Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shfolder.dll'
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\GrooveSystemServices.dll'
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll'
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msxml3.dll'
Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSOHEVI.DLL'

on subsequent calls just 
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shfolder.dll'

Disabling the debugger give the crash again.