# SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() throws an System.AccessViolationException for seemingly no reason

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, savefiledialog

I am trying to use the save file dialog in a windows forms project of mine. When trying to save a file I use the showDialog() method and it throws a System.AccessViolationError. The initial directory of the save file dialog isn't set so I don't see why there is an access violation. Here's the code I wrote for using the save file dialog:

```
var imageSaver = new SaveFileDialog();
imageSaver.Filter = fileType + " File|*." + fileType;
imageSaver.Title = "Save Image";
if (imageSaver.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    b.Save(imageSaver.FileName, imgFormat);
    Close();
}
```

This block of code is used in an event for when a button is clicked, however, after a bit of testing, I found out that the same code works when used in the constructor of the form and in the load event of the form.

Here is the entire class:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Pixart
{
    public partial class ImageGenerator : Form
    {
        int width;
        int height;
        Cell[,] cells;
        ImageFormat imgFormat;
        string fileType;

        bool useMultiplier;

        public ImageGenerator(string fileType, ImageFormat imgFormat, Cell[,] cells, int width, int height)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.cells = cells;
            this.imgFormat = imgFormat;
            this.fileType = fileType;

            titleLabel.Text = "Export " + fileType.ToUpper();

            widthNumber.Minimum = width;
            widthNumber.Increment = width;
            widthNumber.Maximum = (4000 / width) * width;
            heightNumber.Minimum = height;
            heightNumber.Increment = height;
            heightNumber.Maximum = (4000 / height) * height;

            if (heightNumber.Maximum / height < widthNumber.Maximum / width)
                multiplierNumber.Maximum = heightNumber.Maximum / height;
            else
                multiplierNumber.Maximum = widthNumber.Maximum / width;

            widthLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            heightLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            sizeLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            multiplierLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            useMultiplier = true;

            //The code works here for some reason
            //var imageSaver = new SaveFileDialog();
            //imageSaver.Filter = fileType + " File|*." + fileType;
            //imageSaver.Title = "Save Image";
            //if (imageSaver.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            //{
                
            //}
        }

        private void ImageGenerator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //The code also works here
            //var imageSaver = new SaveFileDialog();
            //imageSaver.Filter = fileType + " File|*." + fileType;
            //imageSaver.Title = "Save Image";
            //if (imageSaver.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            //{

            //}
        }

        private void multiplierNumber_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            widthLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            heightLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            sizeLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            multiplierLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            useMultiplier = true;
        }

        private void widthNumber_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            widthLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            heightLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            multiplierLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            sizeLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            useMultiplier = false;

            widthNumber.Value = (widthNumber.Value / width) * width;
        }

        private void heightNumber_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            widthLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            heightLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            multiplierLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark;
            sizeLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            useMultiplier = false;

            heightNumber.Value = (Convert.ToInt32(heightNumber.Value) / height) * height;
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int imageWidth = width * Convert.ToInt32(multiplierNumber.Value);
            int imageHeight = height * Convert.ToInt32(multiplierNumber.Value);
            if (!useMultiplier)
            {
                imageWidth = Convert.ToInt32(widthNumber.Value);
                imageHeight = Convert.ToInt32(heightNumber.Value);
            }

            using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight))
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight / height; y++)
                        {
                            for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth / width; x++)
                            {
                                b.SetPixel((c * (imageWidth / width)) + x, (r * (imageHeight / height)) + y, cells[c, r].Colour);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                var imageSaver = new SaveFileDialog();
                imageSaver.Filter = fileType + " File|*." + fileType;
                imageSaver.Title = "Save Image";
                //line after this throws an error
                if (imageSaver.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    b.Save(imageSaver.FileName, imgFormat);
                    Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void ImageGenerator_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On exactly which line is the exception? Which version of .NET are you running? Are you using any unusual PInvoke or unsafe code?

Comment: Also, can you post the full exception message and stack trace?

Comment: The exception happens on the same line as "imageSaver.ShowDialog()". I am using .NET 4.7.2. I don't think I am using PInvoke or unsafe code but don't exactly know what either are.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560848/folderdialog-box-crashing-only-in-debug-mode-vsd2008/2562190#2562190

Comment: The exception message is System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.' I dont know how to get the stack trace sorry

Comment: To get the stack trace, when Debugging (Debug => Start Debugging) and the exception shows. Click "Copy Details". Open "NotePad" and press ctrl-V to paste the stack trace into Notepad.

Comment: Tried it, all it says is <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: You'll need to post more code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory` in your code is occurring because the Form `Deactivate` event occurs when the `SaveFileDialog` opens.

The issue is due to the following code:

```
private void ImageGenerator_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

**Solution**: Remove `Close()` (or comment it out)

```
private void ImageGenerator_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```